# AWS ALB health check delay

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-application-load-balancer

How can I delay AWS ALB health check until all services have been started on the newly created EC2 instance by autoscaling?

My current health check points to a login page on the app server but some services are not fully up when healt check starts returning success. Is there a way I can add a 2 mins delay before LB starts the health check allowing newly created instance to load all services?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a direct way to do this. You can config the interval time and healthy threshhold to meet your requirements.

For example, you can config interval to 30s and healthy threshold to 5, so that your target will be registered after 30s x 5 = 150s